# How do I safeguard against the OpenSSL vulnerability until I can patch it?

Tags: server-side-attacks

The X509_verify_cert function in crypto/x509/x509_vfy.c in OpenSSL 1.0.1n, 1.0.1o, 1.0.2b, and 1.0.2c does not properly process X.509 Basic Constraints cA values during identification of alternative certificate chains, which allows remote attackers to spoof a Certification Authority role and trigger unintended certificate verifications via a valid leaf certificate. I am interested in mitigating this threat until I can install the patch. Has anybody implemented a viable mitigation technique to safeguard against this vulnerability while waiting for the patch to clear testing?